# Code example proven to fail w/o volatile

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, volatile

Below is a C# code example which is a verbatim translation of a broken Java code (which has proven to break (i. e. the 2nd thread may fail to observe the change of `sharedValue` value) at least on Mac OS X 10.9, Java 1.8 (64 bit), Arrandale (1 socket x 2 core x 2 HT = 4 HW threads)):

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class ThreadTest {
    /* volatile */ private int sharedValue;

    private void RunAsync() {
        while (this.sharedValue == 0);
    }

    private bool Test() {
        Thread t = new Thread(this.RunAsync);
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(10);

        // Yes I'm aware the operation is not atomic
        this.sharedValue++;

        t.Join(10);
        bool success = !t.IsAlive;
        if (!success) {
            Console.Write('.');
        }
        return success;
    }

    static void Main() {
        long failureCount = 0L;
        const long testCount = 10000L;
        for (long i = 0; i < testCount; i++) {
            if (!new ThreadTest().Test()) {
                failureCount++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Failure rate: " + 100.0 * failureCount / testCount + "%");
    }
}
```

Amazingly, no matter many times I run the above C# code on .NET 4.0/Windows XP (32 bit), I haven't observed a single failure. Nor is there any failure when running on Mono (64 bit), Mac OS X. In both cases, I only see a single CPU core busy.

Can you suggest a C# code example which makes an incorrect use of a shared variable and fails unless the variable is marked `volatile`?

Comment: Eric Lippert has some info on this.  He and Joe Duffy seem to imply there is no such scenario on the CLR in x86.  http://blog.coverity.com/2014/03/26/reordering-optimizations/  and  http://joeduffyblog.com/2010/12/04/sayonara-volatile/

Comment: Thanks for the links @MobyDisk. Still, I've already obsrved the above code to break on .NET 4.0/Windows XP (32 bit) in Smithfield (1 socket x 1 core x 2 HT) and Arrandale (1 socket x 2 core x 2 HT), on a bare metal and in the VM, respectively. The key point is running a _release_ build as Matthew Watson suggested below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running the RELEASE build of the following program (do NOT run it from the debugger otherwise the demonstration won't work - so run the release build via "Debug | Start without debugging"):

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private void run()
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(resetFlagAfter1s);
            int x = 0;

            while (flag)
                ++x;

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }

        private void resetFlagAfter1s()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            flag = false;
        }

        private volatile bool flag = true;

        private static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

The program will terminate after a second.

Now remove the `volatile` from the line

```
private volatile bool flag = true; // <--- Remove volatile from this
```

After doing so, the program will now never terminate. (Tested on Windows 8 x64, .Net 4.5)

Please note, however, that in some cases it is more appropriate to use `Thread.MemoryBarrier()` rather than declaring the variable `volatile`, i.e.:

```
while (flag)
{
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    ++x;
}
```

For more information, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/05/12/130935.aspx

Comment: Thanks Matthew! The key point was to run a RELEASE build (I was running a DEBUG build, hence the failure to observe the bug, despite the binary was run outside of a debugger).

Comment: Curious what got optimized away in this case. 
Decompiled code looks pretty much the same except it renames x into num.
If I move x from method body into class level it no longer locks.
If I check x afetr the loop it no longer locks.
Looks like it does not bother to store x in memory just updates regsiter may be, but as soon as I make it visible outside of the method or check it after it correctly does not optimize it away any longer.
Why does it then optimize away the check of the flag even if the flag is public? Seems more like a bug in a compiler than intended behaviour

Answer (score 2):

This should get stuck in an infinite loop (I can't test it right now)

```
public class Test
{
  private bool loop = true;

  public static void Main()
  {
    Test test = new Test();
    Thread thread = new Thread(DoStuff);
    thread.Start(test);

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    test.loop = false;
    Console.WriteLine("loop is now false");
  }

  private static void DoStuff(object o) {
    Test test = (Test)o;
    Console.WriteLine("Entering loop");
    while (test.loop) {

    }
    Console.WriteLine("Exited loop");
  }
```

}