# Update a bool value being used by a thread without lock protection

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I want to know, if trying to update a boolean value being used by a thread is guaranteed to be successful, without any lock protection.

like the following case: 
    there wont be any problem for Stop() to change the boolean member of m_ThreadActive, while threadproc is running?

```
private bool m_ThreadActive = true;

public void threadproc
{
    while (m_ThreadActive)
    {
    ...
    }
}

public void Stop()
{
   m_ThreadActive = false;
}
```

Comment: There won't be any problem but you won't be able to guarantee on which cycle of `threadproc` will the thread exit.

Comment: Without volatile or memory barriers (or similar), there's no guarantee that the thread running `threadproc` won't read `m_ThreadActive` into a CPU register and never load from memory again. I'd personally just use something like a `ManualResetEvent`, unless or until it's demonstrated to have too high a performance overhead for the situation, which I doubt would occur here.

Comment: assuming threadproc() started by a thread, it will not terminate after Stop() is called. actually it will still iterate the threadproc(), just do nothing. OR assuming that threadproc is not started by a thread. there should be no problem, as there is no thread included, thus no lock should be required.

Comment: Every time I notice that this question has been asked again I post a link to this puzzle. http://blog.coverity.com/2014/03/26/reordering-optimizations/.  If you can't figure out the answer then you don't have enough knowledge to elide locks. If you can figure it out then you should know how dangerous and foolish it is to elide locks.

Comment: "actually it will still iterate the threadproc(), just do nothing" - if this is a possible case , it is a serious problem, because there is cleanup processing outside the loop. is this really the case?

Answer (score 5):

It is theoretically possible that the compiler could optimise the loop in such a way that the loop variable always remains true.

To ensure that can't happen, use a [`Volatile.Read()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.volatile.read(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
while (Volatile.Read(ref ThreadActive))
```

If you don't have a version of .Net which supports `Volatile.Read()` you could declare `m_ThreadActive` as `volatile`:

```
private volatile bool m_ThreadActive = true;
```

Or, better, use [`Thread.MemoryBarrier()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.memorybarrier(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
while (ThreadActive)
{
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    // ...
}
```

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24556591/106159) for a program that demonstrates a requirement for `volatile`, `Volatile.Read()` or `Thread.MemoryBarrier()` for it to work correctly.

For more information on why the use of the `volatile` keyword can be a bit suspect, see [this article from Eric Lippert](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three/).