# Use of volatile keyword on the flag field

Tags: c#, multithreading, volatile

I try to understand the use of volatile in multithread context. In the following code from [another source of knowledge](https://www.dotnetperls.com/volatile) on the Internet:

```
class Program
{
    static string _result;
    //static volatile bool _done;
    static bool _done;

    static void SetVolatile()
    {
        // Set the string.
        _result = "Dot Net Perls";
        // The volatile field must be set at the end of this method.
        _done = true;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        // Run the above method on a new thread.
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(SetVolatile)).Start();

        // Wait a while.
        Thread.Sleep(200);

        // Read the volatile field.
        if (_done)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_result);
        }
    }
}
```

The demonstrated use of a **volatile** keyword should prevent a thread from reading a value stored in a cache. Instead of this it should check an actual value.

So without a volatile `_done` should still have a false value (read from the cache) and `Console.WriteLine` statement should not be executed.

Unfortunately running this code in Debug/Release mode without a volatile keyword always produces the output. What is the point of this particular example?

Comment: Without `volatile`, the compiler (static and JIT) *may* optimize the read in such a way that the assignment is never seen, if you go by a strict reading of the standard. But it is not *required* to, and in fact, I don't think any JIT compilers for .NET (past or current) actually do this, at least not this specific case, not on x86/x64.

Comment: If you want to understand such things, then start reading some [serious stuff](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_The_volatile_keyword) maybe?

Comment: *"Before we begin, please note that this example isn't ideal in that it would function correctly without the volatile modifier. It serves only to illustrate the concept of the volatile keyword, not to provide a real-world example"* - from [internet](https://www.dotnetperls.com/volatile).

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24556591/106159) for an example where using `volatile` actually *does* make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

As already said, not using `volatile` keyword does not mean all reads will necessary be cached in all circumstances. They may be cached, or may be not. But if you want more reproducable example, try this:

```
class Program {
    static string _result;
    //static volatile bool _done;
    static bool _done;
    static void SetVolatile() {
        // Set the string.
        _result = "Dot Net Perls";
        // The volatile field must be set at the end of this method.
        _done = true;
    }

    static void Main() {
        // Run the above method on a new thread.
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(SetVolatile)).Start();

        // prevent compiler to throw away empty while loop
        // by doing something in it
        int i = 0;
        while (!_done) {
            i++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("done " + i);
    }
}
```

Here you repeatedly read `_done` in a while loop, increasing possibility it will be cached. Program should terminate with "done" message but will not, because change to `_done` from another thread will not be noticed.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to read ECMA-335, §I.12.6 
Main points are:

- Program **can be optimized** (a lot)
- An optimizing compiler that converts CIL to native code **shall not remove any volatile operation**, **nor shall it coalesce multiple volatile operations into a single operation**

So, in this case, your code *can* be optimized. 
Try the following code:

```
private bool flag = true;
public void LoopReadHoistingTest()
{
    Task.Run(() => { flag = false; });
    while (flag)
    {
      // Do nothing
    }
}
```

In **Debug** mode (without optimizations) it will work fine. In **Release** mode (with optimizations) it will hang forever, because moving the read outside the loop is quite common optimization.
But if you mark field volatile (or use `Volatile.Read` method, or some of `Interlocked` methods) it will work because in that case optimizations are prohibited.

In your example (without loop), `Thread.Sleep` makes an implicit memory barrier (because it's not forbidden and it makes code to work with less surprises), so it will read the value from memory. But I don't see any specification saying that it has to do an implicit memory barrier, so in some implementations it can be not true (or we have to find it in specification).